Python library/CLI for raster to TIN conversion for a DTM
Is there a python library/CLI or a qgis tool/plugin that makes it possible to convert a raster DTM to TIN (in a mesh format like obj for instance). Possibly having as parameters the output format and the interpolation parameters.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
